# How to change the controle depending upon the data type in WPF

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have to Retrieve values from DB using WCF service and fill a dropdown named “Type” with ID-Type values (Use observable collection to bind this).

There should be another control controlled by Data Template/control template, which will be displayed depending upon Type selected. e.g. if   TextBox type is selected then TextBox should be displayed with some default value.

InputType Text box – This will be used to create new type in DB. Use Save button to save value.

Delete Button – This should delete the selected Type from DataBase.

I am done with the DataBase Stuff and all  , but how should i change the controle depending upon the data type in XAML ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a general ContentControl with a style that will select (via Triggers) different ControlTemplates which contain the appropriate control types.

This approach can also be slightly modified to use DataTemplates instead of ControlTemplates (arguably a better approach).  Instead of setting the Template property (which is a ControlTemplate), set the ContentTemplate property (which is a DataTemplate) and fill each DataTemplate with your desired control/s.

```
<Window x:Class="ControlTypeBasedOnComboBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ControlTypes}"
              x:Name="ControlTypeComboBox"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ControlTypeComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <TextBox/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ControlTypeComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="CheckBox">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <CheckBox/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ControlTypeComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="Button">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Button/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

The code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

The View Model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<string> controlTypes;
    public ViewModel()
    {
        controlTypes = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "TextBox", "CheckBox", "Button" };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ControlTypes
    {
        get { return controlTypes; }
    }
}
```

As for the save/delete button, you can also bind the Command properties to different ICommand objects on your View Model based on the SelectedItem of the ComboBox.  I don't know exactly what kind of functionality you need, so I don't know if that's necessary/appropriate.

Hope that helps!